# I was denied entry to South Korea even though I have a valid visa and passport

Tags: visas, south-korea, denial-of-entry, algerian-citizens

I'm an Algerian citizen. I applied for the tourist visa C-3-9, along with my friend. Our visas were issued by the Embassy of the Republic of Korea in Algiers. We bought the tickets and came to Korea (ICN).

My friend went through Immigration without a problem, but they denied me entry. I'm sure everything is legal with my visa and passport, I have no criminal record and never changed my name.

I appealed the decision to refuse entry clearance but, for a second time, they denied my entry.

I will appeal against the decision to the Korean Supreme Court and the Immigration service.

Can anyone give me some advice about the Court and if I have the right to enter?

Comment: Legal advice is unfortunately outside the scope of this site and you've reached the point that you need proper legal advice. Completely unrelated, a few comments: (1) I don't know about the Korean legal system, but is their supreme court really the correct address? (2) read up if you actually had a right to enter. In many countries, getting a visa is only a permission to present yourself at the border, (3) a common case for a visa not being honored at the border is if you were trying to enter for an activity not permitted in your visa category. This could have been the case for you.

Comment: You should have received a paper which explains the reason why you were refused entry. What is written on this paper?

Comment: It should be noted that a visa does not guarantee entry into a country.

Comment: Welcome to the site. While you were issued a visa, when you arrived at the border, were you asked about your travel plans, how much money you had with you (or access to), hotel/hostel reservations? Have you been told a reason (such they don't believe you)? In most cases, being denied entry as a visitor cannot be appealed, as non-citizens don't have a right to be there.  Are you being held in a detention facility? If so, seriously consider whether it is better to have an entry denial on your immigration record, or a deportation order.

Answer (score 4):

From [HiKorea](https://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/main_en.pt), the "e-government for foreigners", that is

> the main site of the electronic government for foreigners, jointly created by the Ministry of Justice, the Ministry of Knowledge Economy and the Ministry of Labor. It was created with the purpose of providing investment, employment, residence, and everyday living related information and services from a single source to foreigners visiting Korea.

A visa is not sufficient to make sure you will be granted entry to South Korea at the Immigration Control:

> **What is VISA?**
>
> - VISA is a kind of endorsement or acknowledgment, whose specific meaning differs from country to country. Generally speaking, however, it is used to mean one of the following two things; One being the *permission to enter* a given country, and the other being the *consul's recommendation for a foreigner's entry request*.
> - In case of Republic of Korea, the latter definition is used. Therefore, **even if one were to have a Korean visa, one can still be denied entry to Korean soil** should an immigration officer find some requirements unsatisfactory after inspection.

I couldn't find any information on how you could appeal against the decision.

Answer (score 2):

As some have pointed out, you shouldn't rely on this site for legal advice.

Did the officer ask you anything? How did you answer? Did you provide, or fail to provide, any document that they asked for? Were you provided with any written or oral explanation for why you were denied entry? Did they search any belongings, checked or carry-ons?

If you really feel unjust, you should talk to an actual attorney and seek professional help.

Do keep in mind, however, that in almost no country a visa (the piece of paper sticked onto your passport) gives you **the right** to enter that country. In fact, whether at the border or after you passed the border, you are always under immigration control. There may be laws protecting an alien from being denied entry or deported, but those law may not always exist and may have limitations. Unless you are a citizen of that country, **you never have the *right* to enter it**.

Travelling to a foreign country is a lot like playing an away game. There may be booing or people throwing stuff at you. Nothing you can do about it. You may face unfair treatment, from either the people living there or the government. You just have to accept it and try again. Finally, I wish you would be able to go on your trip to Korea soon.